# How to require the forked gem lib file ? Name conflicts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I had to fork the gem [Thor](https://github.com/wycats/thor), coz my cli has one command `run` which is reserved in the Thor lib itself, changed its name to millisami-thor just in the `.gemspec` as follows:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
...
  s.name = 'millisami-thor'
...
end
```

and to use it, I pushed the gem under the name `millisami-thor` to rubygems.org and in the Gemfile of my cli project, I put `gem 'millisami-thor', :require => 'thor'`

Now while testing `bundle exec cucumber features` or to try out the executable, just did `./bin/executable --params` and it worked out.

Now, I build the gem with `gem build gemname.gemspec` that generates `gemname.gem` and installed with `gem install gemname.gem` and it gets installed as well as the binary too. Fine, till here.

Now, when I use the binary cmd like `executable --params`, it looks for the original `thor` library instead of the forked one.

I figured out that this was due to the `require ...` in the executable.

```
require 'thor'
require 'fileutils'

require 'gemname/cli'

Cf::CLI.start
```

coz in there I explicitly required the original `thor`.
Now, when I change it to `require 'millisami-thor`, it cannot find and says:

```
...
custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- millisami-thor (LoadError)
...
```

In the Gemfile, I could have done `gem 'millisami-thor, :require => 'thor'` so that it loads the forked gem.
But how can I do the same if its just the `require 'millisami-thor'` ?

The only option I can think of is to change all the class names to 'MillisamiThor' instead of 'Thor' and the file names too. But this will be too messy and ugly.

I could have spotted this if I had installed my gem and test it before. But I did just in the test environment, in which the bundler requires the `millisami-thor`'s `thor` file, so I didn't have this problem till today.

Is there any other way out to achieve this without any messy hacks?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the original gem setup and point Bundler to your git repository fork:

```
gem 'thor', :git => 'git://github.com/yourname/thor.git', :require => 'thor'
```

or even a local path

```
gem 'thor', :path => '/path/to/thor.git', :require => 'thor'
```

Comment: The problem is not with the bundler and Gemfile pointing to my forked github repo. Its when the gem is packaged and installed. I don't think that while building the `.gem` via `gem build gem_name.gemspec`, the forked repo url is considered. Since its CLI app, not like rails, sinatra, etc...